# How can I download contents including pictures of website?

Tags: web

I want to download pictures (picture & description) from couple of websites.
Is there a way to code it?

Answer (score 0):

Right click. Save page as. Done.

This saves the page as html with all currently loaded assets.

Google is your friend.

Close as duplicate.

There is site ripping software out there but I don't recommend it.

and you could also create a crawler that looks for certain fields set by a site and also download the images associated with them.

However I don't condone this kind of thing.

Comment: My question was about all pages under main website not just one page

Comment: Your question is vague. Also you're trying to do a site rip from the looks of it.